# How to parse url with underscoreJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web, underscore.js

I have an url in this format:

```
domain.com/update/item/1
```

How I could retrieve the number 1 from url (for instance, parsing the url) and make me able to use it?

To give some more details about the scenario:

- the page rendered associated with that url is a backbone template
  called by a view
- I need that value 1 to retrieve and than to use it in a html form
- it will be useful if exsist a way to retrieve that value directly from the template page using the inline code (for istance, using <%
  codeHere %>

Comment: Are you using the Backbone router?

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Comment: Yes, perfect. I needed to parse it within the router. Thank you @p4sh4